# Matlab and integrals calculation

Tags: matlab, integral

Can someone help me and tell what is the problem?
I have to calculate some integrals and I keep getting this errors.

Example:

```
quad('(x.^3)*(sqr.((x.^4)+1))',1,8)

??? Error using ==> inline.subsref at 14
Not enough inputs to inline function.

Error in ==> quad at 77
y = f(x, varargin{:});
```

Comment: can you explain more? I dont have "eval" in my guideline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is wrong:

```
(x.^3)*(sqr.((x.^4)+1))
```

is not a legit function.  sqr is not defined, and you can't * if x is a vector.  Do you mean sqrt in place of sqr?  And to fix the *, just use .* (element by element multiplication), but you already know that.

It should be:

```
(x.^3).*(sqrt((x.^4)+1))
```

You can change your code to:

```
quad(@(x)((x.^3).*(sqrt((x.^4)+1))),1,8)
```

or

```
quad('((x.^3).*(sqrt((x.^4)+1)))',1,8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the function first:

```
f = inline ('(x.^3).*(sqrt.((x.^4)+1))'); % define function f(x) = (x^3)*(sqrt(x^4 + 1))
q = quad(f, 1, 8);  %evaluate integral
```

Then you can plot or do whatever you want with q.

Cheers!

Comment: @cleveroid may I ask why you unaccepted my question?